# If there is any technical terminology which describes the odd-even properties of the numbers?

Tags: notation, terminology

Suppose we define a function which returns $1$ if the number is even and $0$ if the number is odd:

$$\begin{align}
     S\left(x\right) =  \left\{\begin{array}{lr}
    0   & \text{if $x$ is odd} \\
    1   & \text{if $x$ is even}
    \end{array}\right.
\end{align}$$

Now, I am wondering if there is word to describe the output of this function? What can I put in the blank below?

The value of S(x) shows the .......... of the number $x$.

I know that one can say other different sentences to imply what this function does, but I am specifically curious to know if there is any technical terminology which describes the odd-even properties of the numbers. This is just an example to make my question more understandable. Thanks.

Comment: "the parity"${}$?

Comment: Parity should be a suitable word

Comment: Thank you guys, would you please post an answer so that I can accept your answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, saying that $S(x)$ displays the parity of $x$ would be just fine.